# Have a cocoa application that opens when I press a key combination

Tags: cocoa, macos

Hey guys, I've finished my little calculator and now what I want to do is this:

I want to be able to run it in the background until I press, say, Control + C and then have it open...is this possible in OS X? I recall it being pretty simple in Windows...where should I begin to look?

I feel like it will involve running as a service or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to have your calculator provide a [Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/). A Service can be assigned a global key combination. When the combination is pressed, your calculator application can open, and ideally, perform a task on the user's current selection.

To assign a service a specific key combination see:

**System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts**
[image]

An alternative approach is to create a background application. This application can register for a global hot key combination. When the combination is pressed, the background application can launch your calculator.

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be better (in a real world application) to set up a background application.  Is this done using LSBackgroundOnly in the info.plist or is there a different method?

Comment: @TotalCocoaNewb LSBackgroundOnly will work for a background app without any UI. It can open your main application, but cannot show a window. If you want it to be able to display an error alert if the application refuses to open, use LSUIElement instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ughoavgfhw.  What I would really like to do is, for example.  Allow the user to set my calculator to open at boot, not as a service or anything, but just as a program.  Then, the program has no visible UI, no menu bar or anything, and is visible only via a Menubar Icon.  When the user presses, say, control+C the calculator becomes visible and is ready to use. So, would LSUIElement work for this?  Thanks again!

Comment: @TotalCocoaNewb: Yes, but I disagree that it would be better. Good services are very useful. The user could select some text and then run your calculator with that input without having to launch your calculator first by any means.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  So would it be better then to have the user create the service or is there a way to do that programmatically?  Keep in mind this of course isn't a shipping product or anything, I'm just learning :).

Comment: @TotalCocoaNewb, take a look at the Service link in the answer above. It links to Apple's Developer documentation for creating and managing Services. You create Services programmatically, but the user can edit the defaults you provide using their System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a setting up a global hotkey.

I found and use the example [here](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/). Which works really well.
There where mixed thoughts on if apple would fully deprecate the Legacy API used,And I think 
there is a new API. But for the life of me can not find it again.!
Ah! found it it was in the NSEvent Class Reference : * addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask*

Comment: Thanks Mark, that looks like a helpful technique, plus it lets me use a little C code as well, so I get that experience as well.  Thanks again!